# Flutter - Dynamic Column Count in Grid Layout

Tags: flutter, grid-layout, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter. 
Like we can override column count for grid layout in Android.
I want to achieve the same thing using Flutter.

Like some of my grid layout items should have one column in one row and for some rows, I need more than one column.
Any idea how to achieve this would be great.

Comment: Did you solve it @Developine?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did not have a grid but my requirements were similar where I did have a requirement of N*M layout that was supposed to be built

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399163/5814422) where i was trying to build a 2D matrix for display
I was able to achieve using nested for loops for each row and column
Also, the number of columns in each of the row were finite (although varying for each row) and known beforehand

Snippet of the code:

```
Widget _buildBody() {
    List<Widget> rows = new List<Widget>(gameBoard.length);
    for (int i=0;i<gameBoard.length; i++){
      List<Widget> cols = new List<Widget>(gameBoard[i].length);
      for(int j=0; j<gameBoard[i].length; j++){
        cols[j] = gameBoard[i][j].column;
      }
      rows[i] = new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: cols,
      );
    }

    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: rows,
      ),
    );
}
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score -1):

You could make the grid for the row with maximum number of columns and then add empty container(s):

```
Container()
```

on where you wan't missing columns:

```
GridView.count(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          // dummy widget to fill [1, 1]
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),

      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
          // dummy widget to fill [2, 2]
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),

      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      Container(
          // dummy widget to fill [3, 3]
      ),
```

Result:

[image: grid with empty tiles]

=======

Comment: Works but expensive